# selinux on squashfs with overlayfs

Tags: ext4, selinux, squashfs

Is it possible to use SELinux on a system with a squashfs root with an overlayfs overlay for read-write operations?

On funtoo (gentoo), I booted with SELinux enabled in permissive mode to see what would happen.  I ran rlpkg -a -r to relabel all files, but none are being relabeled I am guessing because the rootfs is squashfs.

EDIT:

I attempted to re-label the files inside of the chroot environment that I use to build image (EXT4 with xattr support) and no files are getting labeled.  My host environment does support SELinux and is in Permissive mode.